# Trying to find a few stray ISO-8859-1 characters using JavaScript but not sure what the character codes are

Tags: javascript, utf-8, iso-8859-1

In some older data I have, I have been trying to fix some old forum post entries which have some punctuation marks which show up correctly when the page is viewed in ISO-8859-1 in a browser, but when viewed in UTF-8 they show up at those "black diamond with a question mark" invalid character symbols.

The first screenshot shows what one example looks like when viewed in UTF-8, and you can see the smart quotes when I force the browser to view in ISO-8859-1.

If I check a string using JavaScript indexOf() what should I look for to locate those characters? Is there some hex code I should use?

Similarly I'm trying to find single curly quotes, middle dots and long em (dashes). I think if I can hunt those down I can fix everything.

This needs to be done in JavaScript (my server-side programming language).

I think this is probably simple, but I'm not sure what to hunt for.

Thanks for any suggestions.

doug

[image: viewed in UTF-8]
[image: viewed in ISO-8859-1]

Comment: '”'.charCodeAt(0) === 8221

Comment: And that is the non-UTF-8 invalid character character code? What did you do to find that? Edit a file intentionally in ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the char codes in the console pretty easily.

```
"”".charCodeAt(0);  // This is one of the "smart" quotes, 8221.

// This will help you find the codes.
for (var i = 8208; i < 8251; i++) {
  console.log(i, String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

You can use something like this to replace the strings once you know what the char codes are if you're not able to copy/paste the characters into your script for some reason.

```
postText = postText.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8221), 'g'), '"');
```

Comment: This looks just about like what I need, but how do you know you are entering the invalid non-UTF-8 character and getting that code, as opposed to a valid UTF-8 character, which we don't want to replace? I think I cannot just copy/paste the character into my script because the script text file itself is UTF-8 and that would create illegal characters in my script and BBEdit will try to fix them or zap them when I save the file.